# Is there a way to get available camera resolutions from adb shell?

Tags: android, android-camera, adb

I am calling getSupportedPreviewSizes to get a list of resolutions for a few Android devices. Is there a way to get this information without running an app?  Not much is available in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. On Samsung devices (or maybe other devices as well), you need to have the Camera open before you can run dumpsys with media.camera. I basically ran through the following:

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1

adb shell dumpsys media.camera
```

Now i can see all the available resolutions.

Thanks for your help [Droidman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199662/droidman)

Answer (score 1):

run the following adb command:

```
adb shell dumpsys media.camera > info.txt
```

Which will produce a file named `info.txt` in the directory you did run the command from. It will contain a lot of information, I guess you are looking for those lines (output from Nexus 5 2013):

```
      android.scaler.availableProcessedSizes (d0006): int32[34]

    [3264 2448 3200 2400 ]
    [2592 1944 2048 1536 ]
    [1920 1080 1600 1200 ]
    [1280 960 1280 768 ]
    [1280 720 1024 768 ]
    [800 600 800 480 ]
    [720 480 640 480 ]
    [352 288 320 240 ]
    [176 144 ]
```

or (pretty much the same for this particular device)

```
       android.scaler.availableJpegSizes (d0003): int32[34]

    [3264 2448 3200 2400 ]
    [2592 1944 2048 1536 ]
    [1920 1080 1600 1200 ]
    [1280 960 1280 768 ]
    [1280 720 1024 768 ]
    [800 600 800 480 ]
    [720 480 640 480 ]
    [352 288 320 240 ]
    [176 144 ]
```

Comment: I basically went through dumpsys for a Samsung GALAXY S5/S6 device and i see no relevant information. However, i do see it for a Nexus as you mentioned. I guess dumpsys output differs based on the device.

Comment: then my guess is that Samsung decided to hide that particular info